# Celery Schedule run every 10 second

Tags: python, celery, schedule, periodic-task

,I need run my celery every 10 seconds but i must work like this:

- 10:27 - frist run
- 10:30 - second run

My code now like this:

```
#task.py
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks',
include=['main'],
broker="redis://localhost:6379/0")


    
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
 "run-me-every-ten-seconds": {
 "task": "main.generate_data",
 "schedule": 10.0
 }
}
```